# jQuery: Loop through all elemnts in json

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json file that contains the SubmitKey.

```
[
  {
    SubmitKey: "20150907-11-34-08-445"
  },
  {
   SubmitKey: "20150907-12-23-34-263"
  }
]
```

Then I'm using jQuery to call json into array, then checks if the 'KeyID' is in the array or not, using this code:

```
var KeyID = '20150907-12-23-34-263';
jQ.getJSON("data/submit.php", function (myArray){   
    jQ(myArray).each(function() {
            if (this.SubmitKey == KeyID) {
                        alert('I found it');
            }
            else {
                alert('its not in there');
            }
    });

});
```

The idea is to loop through the array and check if the value exist, and come back with an alert of yes or no. The problem, it's showing the alert message for every single object, were I want to only show if its in the entire array or not.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution, you could use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which:

> Returns true if at least one element in this array satisfies the provided testing function.

Your testing function would look something like this:

```
function compareKeyId(element, index) {
    return element.SubmitKey == KeyID;
}
```

Then you'd use it like so:

```
jQ.getJSON("data/submit.php", function (myArray){   
    if(myArray.some(compareKeyId)) {
        alert('Found.');
    }
    else {
        alert('Not found.');
    }
});
```

NOTE: As explained near the bottom of the linked MDN page, Internet Explorer only supports the `some` function from version 9 onwards. If you need to support versions of IE below that then this won't be an option unless you use the suggested polyfill.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Anthony. And yes on my app we don't support IE below 9 so we should be fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, this should work:

```
var KeyID = '20150907-12-23-34-263';
jQ.getJSON("data/submit.php", function (myArray){   
var allOk = true;
jQ(myArray).each(function() {
    if (this.SubmitKey != KeyID) {
       allOk = false;
       break; // If any one element is different, we break the loop
    } 
});
if (allOk) alert('I found It');
```

I hope it helps.

});

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an alert for every object is because you have `alert` statement in your else block.

Remove that else part and you won't get any `alert`s if the keyID is not found in your `myArray`.

If you want to first scan entire array and check if the `KeyID` is present then you can accomplish that by setting a variable to some value and then once the loop is over, verify the value of that variable and then show the alert.

```
var KeyID = '20150907-12-23-34-263';
jQ.getJSON("data/submit.php", function (myArray){   
    var isPresent = false;
    jQ(myArray).each(function() {
        if (this.SubmitKey == KeyID) {
            isPresent = true;
            break;
        }
    });
    if(isPresent){
        alert('I found it`);
    }
});
```